# I can't write a script for winning level in c# for my Unity game.I need help pls

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

In my game, to win a level, You need to get some items into a shopping cart and then you need to go into a trigger.But i have a problem cause i cannot write a script myself (I am learning).when i take one thing with tag Bread into the trigger it ends the level.But i need a script that makes all items with "Bread" tag finish the level and not one item with "Bread" tag.
This is the script that i wrote.PLS help me :)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class SceneSwitch : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        {
            GameObject[] objs;
            objs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Bread");

            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
            }



        }

    }
}
```

There is a video to explain my problem https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OIVGLUwHDA4

Comment: your code finds all "bread" irrelevant of where it is, whatever your cart is made of you need to check if its in there..

Comment: @BugFinder The cart is a 3d object with controller function and all the things with Bread tag are Pickupable objects by the player so if the "Bread" Is in the cart and the cart go into the trigger it pass the level

Comment: right so on the cart you either child the objects, or have a list, or array or something that says "bread is in cart" .. you need to test that not all bread items in the scene

Comment: @BugFinder I am gonna upload a video to explain my problem ok ? Go there https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYz2AKGEpA9SZchAOq5AoyQ?view_as=subscriber To see the video ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like BugFinder commented, it's would be best to make a simple script where you add item  to a list when they are placed in their cart.

Once you move the cart to the end game trigger, you check if it's 2 item of the type "Bread" in the cart, else you trigger another message to tell the player he's missing something.

It's like in your video, you check for the item before going to next level, now you just do it with by iterating through a list. Or if you really want to do it "easy" you could just have a counter for every type of item and do a ++ on that counter when that type is added to the cart ( or -- if removed from the cart) and check if  type >= 2 to verify the trigger to next level event